# Where to find missing files to build ILA assistant

Tags: speech, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to load CMU Pocketsphinx in Windows 10 in  Visual Studio 2013 with the help of this link
https://sites.google.com/site/ilavoiceassistant/how-tos/installing-pocketsphinx

In this, there is a step which says that i have to add Existing items i.e.
"two wrapper files from /JAVA_WRAPPER_FILES folder (pocketsphinx_wrap.c and sphinxbase_wrap.c)."

I have checked every folder provided for the same files but did not found anything.
I have downloaded pocketsphinx from git hub "https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx"

Please help me for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction is not really about pocketsphinx, it covers ILA assistant. The missing files are part of ILA assistant as described in the link, you just need to read it. You unpack ILA assistant sources and copy required files.

> The way I build it was to include the wrapper files (see folder
>   \JAVA_WRAPPER_FILES\ in 'ILA'\SpeechData\Pocketsphinx) in the Visual
>   Studio project supplied by CMU which makes the pocketsphinx.dll
>   redundant.

So you need to look in ILA\SpeechData\Pocketsphinx\JAVA_WRAPPER_FILES\

Just pocketsphinx installation is simple and provided in [README for pocketsphinx itself](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx#ms-windows-ms-visual-studio-2010-or-newer---we-test-with-vc-2010-express)

You can also download a [binary version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-5prealpha-win32.zip/download) if you have trouble to build it.

Comment: Sir, Now I have installed CMU sphinx for intel python 3.5 on Windows 10, and it's working fine. I am working with Hindi model provided with CMU sphinx but its not accurate at all. Now I need to make a more accurate Language model for Hindi language. From where should I start?              Most of the tutorial provided are for LINUX or UNIX but nothing for windows with python and for Hindi Language.

Comment: Tutorial to build models is provided on website http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam. It works on Windows too. It is recommended to use Linux to build models though.

Comment: Is it possible to train and make the provided model more accurate for Hindi language? How?

Comment: For Hindi you have to train a model from scratch.

Comment: Sir what will be the issue in training existing model?

Comment: Existing model is too basic  and small, it's not possible to improve it significantly. For accurate recognition you need much larger model.

Comment: Sir which tool will you recommend for hindi language model?

Comment: I don't understand your last question

Comment: There are many different tools available for making language model.  So which one should I use for hindi language

Comment: srilm is recommended

Comment: sir i am using espeak tool for building the dictionary of hindi(devangri script) so can i make a acoustic model for devnagri script separetly?? or i have to simulate it using english language via unicode format

Comment: You can use devnagri everywhere

Comment: हिन्दी'   --- - - -          ह (B   ह  ि  न (B   न ्  द (B  द  ी (_  ी   ------------  What is the meaning of (B and (_ here as devnagri on its own has no such use of (B and (_ anywhere

Comment: which will be the best lmtk for devnagri??

Comment: srilm is the most advanced and well built toolkit

Comment: hello sir i have started training my model it says there is a mismatch error "phone occurs in dictionary and not in the phonelist"   and "phone occurs in phonelist and not in the dictionary" while the phone it is pointing to is neither  in the dictionary nor in the phonelist

Comment: @Prince, you can share your model folder in order to get more detailed help. I also suggest you to ask a separate question on this problem on sourceforge forum, not here.